# Python: Using BeautifulSoup to save content to CSV

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With the Amazing help of Martijn i came this far in my python programming. However i tried to export the content of my cells to a csv file. I succeeded in importing it, but my resuit is as follows:

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT01718158?term=NCT01718158&rank=1&show_locs=Y#locn').read())

import csv

filename = 'Trial1.csv'

f = open(filename, 'wb')

with f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in soup('table')[5].findAll('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    result = u' '.join([cell.string for cell in tds if cell.string])
    writer.writerow(result)
    print result
f.close()
```

Result: |j|o|h|n|1|2|3

instead of |john|123|    for each particular cell.
How do i correct this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer, but while you are waiting, why don't you print tds, and rewrite the list comprehension as a loop, so you can print each cell.string.  That's how I'd debug it...

Comment: Thanks GreenAsJade for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is your **cell** in **tds** contains `,` but some don't, which the writer got confused. As you know, it's csv writer (Comma Separate Value).

Anyway, just change the **delimiter** should correct the issue you had, like this:

```
...
# I'd suggest using with ... as f as in 1 line
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    # set the delimiter to \t tab than comma
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in soup('table')[5].findAll('tr'):
        tds = row('td')
        # you can writerow the list directly as it will convert it to string for you
        writer.writerow([cell.string for cell in tds if cell.string])
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked!Thanks a million Anzel. Sorry i did not get back here on time cos of the holidays. Thanks a lot for your help.